# Sending Firefox profile to Selenium Grid node displays base64 data in command line

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

When sending the DesiredCapabilities to a Selenium Grid hub and node, what I believe is the custom Firefox profile is completely displayed (at great length, and incredibly slowly) in the command line display for both servers.

The tests do eventually run fine, but it's clearly bottlenecking the process by displaying the whole thing through a CLI.

I don't expect it to be as big of a problem when being executed from Fitnesse, but it concerns me that it could start filling the logs etc.

Any ideas on how to work around this, or am I worrying about something stupid?

Comment: During the creation, the custom profile is really created. And creating new profile takes a while. You can switch to ChromeDriver. But generally, I think you worry about something you should not

Comment: I can see the profile creation taking the time it does, but in the process of communicating that profile to the Hub/Node server the entire profile (which is massive when viewed in base64) is displayed in the command window - scrolling random characters for about 2-5 minutes - which doesn't seem normal.